# Cannot Invoke 'sendData' with an argument list type '(Int32, toPeers: [AnyObject]!,

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

... withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode, error: inout NSError?)'

I am attempting to send this time over multipeer connectivity so that I can start a function at the same time across all devices, however I keep receiving the error above, here is a code snippet, please feel free to ask questions or if my code needs to be more in depth or is lacking explanation.

```
@IBAction func pickS(sender: AnyObject) {


    self.presentPicker(sender)


    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestView: playMusicViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! playMusicViewController
        DestView.selectedSong = MPMediaItemCollection()

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

        //formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)  // you can set GMT time
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() // or as local time
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss:SSS"



        formatter.dateFormat = "HHmmssSSS"
        var Time = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        var startTime = (Time as NSString).intValue + 100
        println(startTime)
        let msg = startTime

        var error : NSError?

        self.session.sendData(msg, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error: &error)

        if error != nil {
            print("Error sending data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }

       // self.updateChat(self.messageField.text, fromPeer: self.peerID)

        //self.startTime.text = ""

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

the first argument of the method `sendData:toPeers:WithMode:error` must be a NSData object, not an Int32

Answer (score 0):

The object supplied to the `toPeers` parameter must have be an [array of `MCPeerID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCSession/sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:). Does your `self.session.connectedPeers` property have that type?

**Edit:**

After a re-reading of the question, you need to convert your `msg` into an object of type `NSData`. It's an `Int` now. I'm not sure what you are trying to send, but let's say if you want to send the current date & time:

```
let now = NSDate()
let nowData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(now)
var error : NSError?

self.session.sendData(nowData, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error: &error)
```

Comment: I am sorry, could you elaborate? As the only time that I include connectedPeers in my code is within this function

Comment: @Matt how's your `connectedPeers` initialized? It must be set to something before use

Comment: I am pretty sure connectedPeers comes with multipeer connectivity by default without being initialized, I used this http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/09/multipeer-connectivity-on-ios-8-with-swift.html as help and it seems to work there without being initialized